# I want to show a title with the H2 tag

Tags: php

Could someone look at this.

I want to show `echo htmlspecialchars($title)` in `<h2>` but everything I tried I get a blank page.

```
<div class="adsmanager_ads_desc">
    <?php $strtitle = "";
    if (@$this->positions[5]->title) {
        $strtitle = JText::_($this->positions[5]->title);
    } 
    echo "<h2>" . @$strtitle . "</h2>"; 

    if (isset($this->fDisplay[6]))
    {   
        foreach($this->fDisplay[6] as $field) {
        $c = $this->field->showFieldValue($this->content,$field); 
        if ($c != "") {
            $title = $this->field->showFieldTitle(@$this->content->catid,$field);

                if ($title != "") {
                    echo htmlspecialchars($title).": ";
                    echo "$c<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you close `?>` and then immediately reopen `<?php`?

Comment: `if (@$this->positions[5]->title) {$strtitle = JText::_($this->positions[5]->title);} ` is not working.. try to correct it..

Comment: I discourage the use of the @ it breaks more then you can guess (literlay debugging is a guessing game if you use it)

Second I edit the code so it was viewable and edded some {} so try it again

Comment: Remove all `@`. You may be suppressing a useful error message

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, and if it throws errors say what they are

```
<div class="adsmanager_ads_desc">
    <?php 
    $strtitle = (is_string($this->positions[5]->title)) ? $this->positions[5]->title : '';
    echo "<h2>" . $strtitle . "</h2>"; 

    if (isset($this->fDisplay[6]) && is_array($this->fDisplay[6]))
    {   
        foreach($this->fDisplay[6] as $field) {
            $field_value = $this->field->showFieldValue($this->content, $field); 
            if (is_string($field_value) && strlen($field_value) > 0) {
                $title = $this->field->showFieldTitle($this->content->catid,$field);

                if (is_string($title) && strlen($title) > 0) {
                    echo htmlspecialchars($title).": " . $field_value . "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

I also added some is_string etc, this is not neccessary but can help debuging (although if it is a int|double it should pass too probably

Comment: hi, thanx for the reply, i'm a newbee in php but now it trows "ADSMANAGER_POSITION_DESCRIPTION3" instead of the real title.

Comment: Well it is not in the code so probably your variable is "ADSMANAGER_POSITION_DESCRIPTION3". That part we can't fix

Answer (score 0):

You are suppressing errors and wondering what is wrong. In development, error reporting is your friend.

Instead of this

```
if (@$this->positions[5]->title) {
    $strtitle = JText::_($this->positions[5]->title);
}
```

Try this

```
$strtitle = JText::_($this->positions[5]->title) || "Error bro";
```

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry i think you mean the wrong title. This one is working. it is the title in this peace $title = $this->field->showFieldTitle(@$this->content->catid,$field);
      if ($title != "")
       echo htmlspecialchars($title).": ";
      echo "$c<br/>";

Comment: And this one i get not in <h2> but it is the right one that i already test

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this

```
<h2><?php  echo htmlspecialchars($title).": "; ?></h2>
```

Can you try this also

```
    <div class="adsmanager_ads_desc">
         <?php $strtitle = "";
        if (@$this->positions[5]->title) {
            $strtitle = JText::_($this->positions[5]->title);
        } 
        echo "<h2>" . @$strtitle . "</h2>"; 

        if (isset($this->fDisplay[6]))
        {   
            foreach($this->fDisplay[6] as $field) {
            $c = $this->field->showFieldValue($this->content,$field); 
            if ($c != "") {
                $title = $this->field->showFieldTitle(@$this->content->catid,$field);

                    if ($title != "") {
                          echo '<h2>'.htmlspecialchars($title).':'.'</h2>';
                          echo "$c<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes i want that piece, but this is not working i already tried that

Comment: @BennyVanDenHeuvel What is the output you getting in that echo ?

Comment: what is the result of `echo htmlspecialchars($title)`

Comment: this is the result in frontend: "Gevraagde dienst: Helpen met het schrijven van teksten"
Source: http://dienstenruil.be/13-computer-reparatie-ondersteuni/26-computer-herstel

Comment: Gives me a blank page sorry.

Comment: but if i tried this one echo "<div class=\"h2\">test</div>"; it works fine anny sugestions

Comment: @BennyVanDenHeuvel I have edited the code. Please try this . I have used `":" to ':'`

Comment: Please take a look on the site to see what output i have maybe you can see what is wrong now. http://dienstenruil.be/13-computer-reparatie-ondersteuni/26-computer-herstel

Comment: the variable tittle is "" can i change that in a text or something ?

Comment: `str_replace('""',"Some text here",$title);` for replacement . I am still checking the other case

Comment: I mean that the variable is ":" but you changed it to ':' but not where the variable is created "if ($title != "")" as you can see here. I would like to thank you for the support. i'm a newbee to php

Comment: @BennyVanDenHeuvel I have changed the code. Please use this . Hope this will work. :)

Comment: that did not work, blank page but i think i can get it like this:echo "<div class=\"h2\">$title:</div>";

Comment: @BennyVanDenHeuvel Please accept the answer if it worked for you and please make one vote up too :)